# GradleCompatible issue using android support and androidx.*

Tags: android, back4app

I'm trying to test my app connection to Back4App .. I download the template at Back4App’s GitHub repository, but as noticed on Back4App docs I have to update the version of Parse SDK for Android to the latest on, so when I do I get this error..

I expect to get connected to Back4App but I got this error here  `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'` saying:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qozQ.png)

```
"Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='support-core-utils', myVersion='27.1.1', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.core', myArtifactId='core', myVersion='1.0.1', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... 
    Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible"
```

Answer (score 0):

The project looks like to have a compatibility issue.

At the moment, I would like to recommend you the repository below:

https://github.com/charlesb4a/push-notification-android

With the link above, you'll find an example working with the latest version.

It also has the Push configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

SOLLUTION IS :
You need to Migrate to Androidx Since Firebase is updated, and use androidx.
Or Else
Use an Older version of firebase

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate